# Writing HTML with PHP variable to an external file

Tags: php

How do i write a variable as string to an external file using fwrite - with the single quotations '(var)' around the variable:

```
 $sql_data_element =  "UPDATE artister SET data_two="$data_two" WHERE brugernavn= ' . $brugernavn . '";
```

Writing data_two="$data_two" gives an error - needs proper escaping to work...

Hers the full code to be written to external file:

```
$file = fopen($dir . '/' . $file_to_write,"w");

$template_content = '  
<article class="text" style="display:block">
<div class="wrap_om_artisten_top clearfix"> <!-- CLEAR FLOATS I wrap_profile_image OG data_elements_upload_section -->

    <!-- PROFIL FOTO -->    
    <div class="wrap_profile_image"> 
        <figure class="profile_image">
            <!-- PROFIL FOTO HER -->
        </figure>

        <div class="wrap_form_image">
            <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" class="form_img_profile"> 
                <input type="file" name="img_profile_upload" id="img_profile_upload" style="display:none;" accept="image/*"  />  
                <label for="img_profile_upload" class="choose_profile_img button">Vælg billede</label> 
                                                                            <!-- LABEL: OMGÅ BROWSER DEFAULT-TEXT: "Ingen fil valgt." -->       
                <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit_image_profile" value="Tilføj foto" class="submit_img_upload button">                  
            </form>
        </div>  
    </div>

    <!-- INOF -->
    <div class="data_elements_upload_section"> 

        <!-- INDSÆT DATA ELEMENT I MYSQL -->
        <?php
            $conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
            if ($conn->connect_error) {
                die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
            } else {
                //echo("ja conn ok <br />");
            }

            // HVIS DER ER INDTASTET NOGET ("isset") I FORM INPUT...    
            $data_one = isset($_POST["data_one"]) ? $_POST["data_one"] : "";    
            $data_two = isset($_POST["data_two"]) ? $_POST["data_two"] : "";    
            $data_three = isset($_POST["data_three"]) ? $_POST["data_three"] : "";  


            // ERRORS
            function show_error_data($error_text) {
                echo    \'<div class="error_overlay"> \n\';
                echo        \'<div class="error_text_wrap"> \n\';
                echo            \'<p class="error_text">$error_text</p>\'; // HUSK FORSKEL PÅ ENKELT - OG DOBBELT
                echo            \'<button class="error_close">Prøv igen</button> \n\';
                echo        \'</div> \n\';
                echo    \'</div>\';
            }

            // HVIS FORM SUBMIT ER TRYKKKET...
            if (isset($_POST["submit_data_one"])) {     
                // BESTEM HVOR OG HVAD DER SKLA INDSÆTTES
                $sql_data_element =  "UPDATE artister SET data_one='\$data_one' WHERE brugernavn= \'' . $brugernavn . '\'";
                //INDSÆT INDTASTEDE DATA I MYSQL
                $conn -> query($sql_data_element);
            }
            else if (isset($_POST["submit_data_two"])) {        
                if (empty($_POST["data_one"])) { // HVIS data_one ER TOM..
                    show_error_data("Udyld Info 1 først!");
                } else {    
                    $sql_data_element =  "UPDATE artister SET data_two="$data_two" WHERE brugernavn= ' . $brugernavn . '";
                    $conn -> query($sql_data_element);
                }
            } // END OF submit_data_two
            else if (isset($_POST["submit_data_three"])) {  
                if ( (empty($_POST["data_one"])) || (empty($_POST["data_two"])) ) {
                    show_error_data("Udyld Info 1 og 2 først!");
                } else {    
                    $sql_data_element =  "UPDATE artister SET data_three="$data_three" WHERE brugernavn= ' . $brugernavn . '";
                    $conn -> query($sql_data_element);
                }
            } // END OF submit_data_three           
        ?>

        <aside class="wrap_data_elements"> 
    <!--        <button type="button" class="wrap_close_text">
                <img src="/images/slideren/icons/icon_close_fullscreen.png" class="close_text" 
                    alt="Skjul informationer om kunsteneren og vend tilbage til visning af kunsteksemksempler" />
            </button>-->



            <div class="data_element">
                <h1>' . $brugernavn . '</h1>
            </div>          

            <div class="data_element">
                <?php 
                    $query = "SELECT data_one FROM artister WHERE brugernavn = ' . $brugernavn . '"; 
                    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die (mysqli_error($conn) );

                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                        $data_one = $row["data_one"];
                        echo $data_one;
                    }
                ?>
            </div>
            <div class="data_element">
                <?php 
                    $query = "SELECT data_two FROM artister WHERE brugernavn = ' . $brugernavn . '";
                    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die (mysqli_error($conn) );

                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                        $data_two = $row["data_two"];
                        echo $data_two;
                    }
                ?>
            </div>  
            <div class="data_element">
                <?php 
                    $query = "SELECT data_three FROM artister WHERE brugernavn = ' . $brugernavn . '"; 
                    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die (mysqli_error($conn) );

                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                        $data_three = $row["data_three"];
                        echo $data_three;
                    }
                ?>
            </div>  

            <!--<ul class="wrap_se_mere">     
                <li class="overskrift_se_mere">DENNE KUNSTNER HAR MERE</li> 
                    <ul class="second_se_mere">   
                        <li class="se_mere">MUSIK</li>
                        <li class="se_mere">kunst</li>
                        <li class="se_mere">FILM</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>   -->      
        </aside>

        <div class="wrap_form_data">
            <button class="show_form_data button">Opret info</button>

            <!-- OPRET DATA ELEMENT 1 -->
            <form action="<?=$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]?>" method="post" class="form_data_element">
                <input type="text" name="data_one" placeholder="Data 1" class="data_input"/>
                <input type="submit" name="submit_data_one" class="submit_data button" value="Opret data 1" />      
            </form> 
            <!-- OPRET DATA ELEMENT 2 -->
            <form action="<?=$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]?>" method="post" class="form_data_element">
                <input type="text" name="data_two" placeholder="Data 2" class="data_input"/>
                <input type="submit" name="submit_data_two" class="submit_data button" value="Opret data 2" />      
            </form> 
            <!-- OPRET DATA ELEMENT 3 -->
            <form action="<?=$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]?>" method="post" class="form_data_element">
                <input type="text" name="data_three" placeholder="Data 3" class="data_input"/>
                <input type="submit" name="submit_data_three" class="submit_data button" value="Opret data 3" />        
            </form> 
            <button class="cancel_data button"></button>
        </div>
    </div>  <!--    end of data_elements_upload_section -->

</div> <!-- END OF wrap_om_artisten_top -->



    <!-- VIS BESKRIVELSE -->
    <div class="wrap_om_artisten_bottom_broedtekst">    
        <?php
            $conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
            $query = "SELECT beskrivelse FROM artister WHERE brugernavn = \'' . $brugernavn . '\' ";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die (mysqli_error() );

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                $beskrivelse = $row["beskrivelse"];
                echo $beskrivelse;
            }
        ?>
    </div> <!-- END OF wrap_om_artisten_bottom_broedtekst -->   


    <!-- OPRET BESKRIVELSE -->
    <form action="<?=$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]?>" method="post" class="form_beskrivelse">
        <label>Beskrivelse:</label>
        <textarea id="editor1"  name="beskrivelse" placeholder="Beskrivelse her"        
            value="<?php echo isset($_POST["beskrivelse"]) ? $_POST["beskrivelse"] : ""; // UPLOAD TEXT TIL MYSQL ?>">
            <?php echo $beskrivelse; // VIS OG EDIT EKSISTERENDE MYSQL-TEXT ?>
        </textarea>
        <script>
            // VIS ckeDITOREN
            CKEDITOR.replace( "editor1" );
        </script>
        <br />

        <input type="submit" name="submit_beskrivelse" value="Opret beskrivelse" />     
    </form>


    <!-- ART UPLOADS -->
    <div class="wrap_uploads" >
    <?php
        include ("links_art_uploads.php");
    ?>
    </div>

    <div class="upload_section">    
        <form id="Upload" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
            <p>
                <label>Upload et billede:</label>
                <!-- TYPE file FINDER IMG LOCATION - id + CCS-STYLE + button MED JS ER HER FOR AT OMG? BROWSER-DEFAULT TEXTEN: "Ingen fil valgt." -->
                <input type="file" name="img_art_upload" id="img_art_upload" style="display:none;" 
                accept="image/*"  onchange="showMyImage(this)"/>  <!-- TIL PREVIEW - SE script function showMyImage OG body <input type="file"... -->
                <button type="button" class="input_style button" onClick="document.getElementById("img_art_upload").click();">Vælg billede</button>
            </p>

            <p>
                <label>Skift navn på billede</label>
                <input type="text" name="img_nyt_navn" maxlength="26" /> 
            </p>

            <p>
                <label>Press to...</label>
                <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit_art_upload" class="button" value="Upload">

            </p>    
        </form>
    </div>  



<!--    <div class="preview_wrap"style="position: absolute; bottom: 0; border: 2px solid red;">
        <img id="preview" class="preview_size"/> <!-- TIL PREVIEW - SE script og <input type="file"...  -->
    </div>-->

<!-- vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv -->

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){   

    // PROFIL FOTO - HENT OG VIS FRA ROOT 
    $("figure.profile_image").load("links_to_uploads_template.php");

    // PROFIL FOTO - TOGGLE BUTTONS
    $("label.choose_profile_img").click(function() {
        $(this).hide(); 
        $("input.submit_img_upload").fadeIn(400);
        $("body").css({"background" : "black" });
    }); 

    // TIL UPLOAD AF SATA
    $("form.form_data_element").hide();

    $("button.show_form_data").click(function() {
        $(this).hide();
        $("form.form_data_element:nth-of-type(1)").fadeIn(400); 
        $("form.form_data_element:nth-of-type(2)").fadeIn(400); 
        $("form.form_data_element:nth-of-type(3)").fadeIn(400); 
    });

    $("form.form_data_element").click(function() {
        $("form.form_data_element").not(this).hide();
        $(this).css({"float" : "left"}); // KUN NØDVENDIG PGA FOMM 3 SOM FLOATER RIGHT - HVILKET PALCERER button.cancel_data YDERST TIL VENSTRE 
        $(this).css({"width" : "calc(100% - 30px)"}); // BREDDE FORM MINUS BREDDEN AF button.cancel_data 30PX
        $(this).find("input.data_input").css({"float" : "left", "width" : "calc(100% - 120px)"}); // BREDDE MINUS input.submit_data
        $(this).find("input.submit_data").fadeIn(400);
        $("button.cancel_data").fadeIn(400);
    });

    $("button.cancel_data").click(function() {
        $("button.show_form_data").fadeIn(400);
        $(this).hide();
        $("form.form_data_element").removeAttr("style").hide();
        $("input.data_input").removeAttr("style");
        $("input.submit_data").removeAttr("style");
    }); 

var half_height = $(window).height() / 2;


$("button.next_image").click(function() {
    var viewport_height = $(window).height(); // OGSÅ DEFINERET I custom_fullscreen.js
    var next_image = $(this).next(".window_element").outerHeight(true); // HØJDE + MARGIN + PADDING 
    $("html, body").animate({
//      scrollTop: $(".top_img").offset().top - ( $(window).height() - $(".top_img").outerHeight(true) ) / 2
        scrollTop: $(".top_img").offset().top - ( viewport_height - next_image ) / 2
    }, 1000, "swing");
});

//var position = $(".window_element").offset(); /*it gets the position of the div
//                                     "fixed" relative to the document*/
//$(".window_element").html(position.top); 


}); // END OF DOC READY
</script>   

</article> <!-- END OF article class="text" -->
'; // END OG HTML 

fwrite($file, $template_content);

fclose($file);
```

After writing the external file the HTML must be like this:

```
$sql_data_element =  "UPDATE artister SET data_one='$data_one' WHERE username='new user' ";
```

*What this is about:* After submitting username, password to MySql the "index.php" writes a new file from `$template_content` and redirects to this. Based on written content of new file user has more options.

Comment: update your question as to what the content of the file is now, and/or a var_dump.

Comment: I have updated the content -

Comment: I don't know why you're trying to write all that out in a file. You're using what appears to be pure html first, then a db query with no php tags around it and then js. I feel that you need to rethink this. Like I mentioned above; update your question with the output you're presently getting. It seems that you're wanting to exclude the html and js and only write the query to the file, am I right?

Comment: Ok - maybe some explanation is necessary: After submitting username, password to MySql the "index.php" writes a new file from $template_content and redirects to this. Based on written content of new file user has more options.

Comment: Basically i need to know how to add the variable '$data_one' to the new file so that it can be used when submitting more data to MySql - i just need the right syntax when writing  $data_one so i can be used on external file

Comment: you need to update your question instead with what you're writing in comments. I can't help you with this, sorry.

Comment: Fred fair enough - i will delete

Comment: Writes a file and then redirects to it? Sounds like bad design to me. Should you just redirect to a page that would process the data in the same way based on the user?

Comment: Consider a log-in page called index:php: after submitting username etc to MySql you wil be redirected to a newpage.php - created by index.php as described in code. On newpage.php you have further options. Basic or?

Comment: Why would you need a "new page" for that? That is not how dynamic applications are implemented. Usually you use a fixed implementation, inside that you dynamically create content and inject options or features, whatever, depending on the authorization of the user logged in. Writing a new file for each user sounds like a huge overhead and introduces a whole zoo of security issues. Rule of thumb: a web application should never be able to modify its own implementation.

Comment: Did you consider using a nowdoc instead? http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - nice as im quite new to backend developing. Your answer wants me ask how you create new content, options and features at the same page as you use as index. Ive used DOMDocument with very little luck  - extremely unstable when it comes to rewriting special characters UTF-8 which i have to implement. fwrite works well as described in full code

Comment: Using HEREDOC throws error, unexpected '"', on $data_one = isset($_POST["data_one"]) ? $_POST["data_one"] : "";

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention to your quote chars and use `heredoc` for enhanced readability:

```
<?php

$username = 'James Bond';
$template_content = <<<CODE
\$sql_data_element = "UPDATE artister SET data_one='\$data_one' WHERE username='$username'";
CODE;

var_dump($template_content);
```

The output of above obviously is:

```
string(91) "$sql_data_element = "UPDATE artister SET data_one='$data_one' WHERE username='James Bond'";"
```

Comment: Cant use HEREDOC - the $template_content contains both PHP, HTML and JQuery to be used on external file

Comment: @jan199674 I don't understand that statement - what a string contains or how it is used at a later point in time is irrelevant for its definition. You can mix whatever markup or code you want in such a string definition. No difference between classical or `heredoc` style string definition in that.

Comment: @arkascha Did you see their edit? I honestly don't know what they're trying to do here; see [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42392330/writing-html-with-php-variable-to-an-external-file?noredirect=1#comment71933428_42392330) under it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Indeed things are much more fuzzy now considering that "update" of the question. However @jan199674 I still do not understand what all that speaks against the usage of `heredoc` if you really want to follow that architecture...

Comment: @arkascha Indeed. A nowdoc would be another option http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc

Comment: Thanks - pointing in the right direction i think allthough i already gave heredoc a try before asking. Will test ´more and of course upvote if it works

Comment: I was hoping for a simple solution on the maybe not so simple issue - code works except for the adding of single qoutes after write

Comment: As already mentioned: this whole question looks a bit like you are making something very complicated without need. It might make sense to discuss your architecture / approach with someone experienced in such questions. Simply to prevent that you invest a lot of time and effort into something that might possibly to be solved in a much more straight forward manner...

Comment: Apart from that: the specific point of this answer is _not_ the usage of `heredoc` or `nowdoc`. They are just alternate means to define a string, they do not add any additional features. They simply make code more readable and thus easier to maintain.

Comment: So problem not solved? How to apply single quotes when writing to external file. About the comments on architeture it would be nice to elaborate a bit further instead of just dismissing

Comment: Well, I already mentioned before that your approach appears highly unorthodox... I already elaborated on a few details of that, but you gave no response to those points. Maybe your situation is so specific that our approach definitely makes sense, but so far you failed to provide any details that justifies such a statement. Actually all I saw can be done by a simple dynamic script which is exactly what php is there for. So why the need to create "pages" on the fly with all the need to cleanup later, all the security implications and the obvious issues you are struggling with right now?

Answer (score 0):

```
$template_content = '$sql_data_element =  "UPDATE artister SET data_one="\'$data_one\'" WHERE username= \'' . $username . '\'";';
```

will output

```
$sql_data_element =  "UPDATE artister SET data_one='$data_one' WHERE username='new user' ";
```

as you requested

Are you sure you do not want to output

`$sql_data_element =  "UPDATE artister SET data_one='some value' WHERE username='new user' ";` ?

Comment: Already tried that - HTML will be both single and double quotes:
data_one="'$data_one'"
I need it with only single quotes:
data_one='$data_one'